# How to change the height of CollapsingToolbarLayout with fragment inside?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a activity with CollapsingToolbarLayout and fragment inside. CollapsingToolbarLayout has *wrap_content* height. The fragment height is set to *wrap_content* too. When all data are loaded the fragment height changes, but CollapsingToolbarLayout's height is still as it was before. Because of that the part of fragment is cut, and part of it is not visible to the user.

My idea is that in the fragment I have the observer and when data is loaded, Ive send the measured height to the activity via listener. There I was trying to set LayoutParams for fragment and use *invalidate()* and *requestLayout()* methods on the fragment and CollapsingToolbarLayout but it doesnt work.

Do you know how to fix this?

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar"/>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/other_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contraints=".." />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/comments_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contraints=".."/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You should use scrollable container to work with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman What do you mean by scrollable container? The point is that in this container I have the recyclerView. This recyclerView have a huge amount of data. When I use the nestedScrollView as a parent for this fragment the performance for this recyclerView is terrible bad. This is workaround for this problem.

Comment: Set `scrollFlags` to your `RecyclerView` which shrink the Toolbar during scrolling

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I believe that you meant not `RecyclerView` but fragment. So in your opinion which flag should I used?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I was trying to set all of the options and nothing works :/

Comment: Can you add your fragment layout?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman added in the main post :)